# Exclude one class from creating a Table in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, persistence.xml

I have a persistence unit like this:

```
  <persistence-unit name="persistence Unit"
        transaction-type="JTA">     
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.example.User</class>
        <class>com.example.Team</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes />

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> 
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
            <!-- JTA stuff -->
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.BTMTransactionManagerLookup" />
        </properties>               
    </persistence-unit>
```

When the server loads first time, this creates table for `User` and `Team`, but i dont want to create a table for `Team`. Is it possible?

Some settings in the persistence table maybe?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Why do you even want this? Hibernate needs the tables, or it will throw an exception during startup. And as you use update, `Team` won't be touched if it already exists.

Comment: Yes, i understand in normal circumstances i would not want to do this.However, i have opensource framework, which creates tables if its not there, so i dont want tables to be created by this persistence unit, Because it gets excecuted by the opensource as a routine startup, how ever i have additional custom classes like user . which i want to create.

Comment: So why do you need it? Do you want to create the table by a separate script or something?

Comment: I see. As far I know, no it is not possible by using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`.

Comment: In this blog post, SchemaFilter is used for that: https://medium.com/@horiaconstantin/excluding-hibernate-entities-from-auto-generation-bce86f8e6d94

Answer (score 0):

If table `Team` isn't changed (INSERT or UPDATE) by your application in any way, you could remove write permissions for it in your database system.

Answer (score -1):

Exclude `Team` class from your `persistance.xml` Remove following line.

```
<class>com.example.Team</class>
```

Comment: Nope, then, pesistence would fail, wouldn't it ?

Comment: Why Persistance will failed? I do'nt understand.

Comment: @MasudCSECUET Hibernate needs to know about `Team`. Removing it from the configuration surely solves the problem, but would also most likely prevent Hibernate from accessing the table.